# Linksys E2500 - Terrible WiFi speed

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router

I have a Linksys E2500 router that is resulting in terrible WiFi speed.  With a wired connection, I have the following results (I pay for 50 Mbps speed):

[image: Wired speed test]

With wireless, at best it reaches 20% on a good day:

[image: Wireless speed test]

Most of the time my speed barely reaches 6 Mbs.  This is even when my device is the only device connected to the router (wireless and wired).  Also note that my device has an [Intel Centrino Wireless-N 1030 Adapter](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/centrino/centrino-wireless-n-1030-brief.html).

I have tried many things to improve my wireless speed, most with little success, including:

- Changing the channel to an unused channel in my area (i.e. channel 2)
- Limiting the channel width (i.e. 20 MHz only)
- Enabling/Disabling QoS and WMM
- Finding and setting the optimal DNS server (using [Namebench](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/centrino/centrino-wireless-n-1030-brief.html))

I can also confirm that there is only one wireless device near the router that could possibly interfere (an LG 47LN5700 TV).  However the wireless feature is not being used; it is connected directly into the router with an Ethernet cable.  Prior to the current location, the router was in a room with no other wireless devices with which it could interfere and I still experienced the same behaviors.

Beyond my experimenting, I am failing to find any reason why my router is producing awful WiFi speed when it can support up to 300 Mbs speeds.  I appreciate any recommendations for improving my WiFi speed.

Comment: You mention your router can support 300 MBps, are you sure your client can?  Do you know if your client is using 2.4 GHz or 5 GHz?  Lots of things besides network devices could produce interference . . .

Comment: Thank you for the comment.  I completely forgot to mention my device's wireless adapter.  It is an Intel Centrino Wireless-n 1030.  According to Intel's website, the adapter has a capability of 300 Mbps of WiFi receive bandwidth.

Comment: Can you give me the model number of your laptop? I think it may be that the laptop only has a wireless 802.11/a/b/g and does n

Comment: @AlexBrooks, you mention setting your AP to channel 2, for your sake and those of your neighbors, please only use channels 1, 6 or 11.  Also, what version are the drivers for your wireless adapter?  Go to the [Intel Support](http://www.intel.com/p/en_US/support/detect) site and run their auto-detect tool to make sure you are up to date.  In addition, make sure you have upgraded your Linksys' firmware.

Comment: The Centrino Wireless-N 1030 is limited to the 2.4 GHz spectrum, so you won't get dual-band, and you could be getting interference from cordless phones, microwaves, etc.  The E2500 has also been [reported to have bad performance at 2.4 GHz](http://reviews.cnet.com/routers/linksys-e2500-multiple-user/4505-3319_7-34535355-2.html)

Comment: @ernie Sorry for the late response.  I plan on purchasing a new router (different from the E2500) to see if the connection speeds are still the same.  As soon as I get some results, I will post.  If the speed is better, I will accept an answer from you if you post the same info as in your previous comment.

Comment: @YLearn why do you suggest using only channels 1, 6, or 11?  If you can explain the benefits of those channels or the negative aspects of the other channels, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: 1, 6, and 11 are the 3 channels that won't overlap.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_WLAN_channels.  Also, you might just get a USB wifi adapter that supports 5 GHz and try that . . . if there's interference in the 2.4 GHz from a phone, microwave, etc, you'll still have crap performance with a router that's got better 2.4 GHz performance than the E2500 (as you're stuck using the 2.4 GHz spectrum with the Centrino 1030)

Comment: @ernie Thank you for the reference.  I will change the channel back to one of the listed.  Regarding the adapter, I agree that it could be a plausible solution.  However my laptop is not the only device with the issue.  I have many devices that connect to the router and don't want to resort to spending a lot of money on adapters for everything.

Comment: Take a look at this, for a more in depth look at why channels 1, 6, and 11 are important http://serverfault.com/questions/471721/adjacent-channel-versus-co-channel-interference

Answer (score 1):

The WiFi signal is lossy, the distance between your machine and the access point greatly affects transfer speed. If you have another PC, you can find out by yourself by sending some files over ftp.

Furthermore, even though an ap is one one channel, the signal interferes with others. Its like a parabola. If you can, you should pick a channel that does not overlap. These are 1, 6, and 11.

If another ap is on channel 1, do not use channel 2, since there will be too many interferences. It is actually better to stay at channel 1 since there are collision prevention algorithms that are used.

Answer (score 0):

10 mbps is not a good speed these days. Lets not confuse wifi connection with internet speed. I test 25 Mb with linksys E2500 with charter internet. Keep in mind your wifi speed is limited by the device, for example ios devices and android may not support higher wifi speeds. When signal is good I connect to my router at 52 mb with ios devices. With newer computer that support AC wifi I get as much as 100 mb. (again not internet but internal wifi speeds) so if yout router says it supports speeds up to 300 MBS you will not achieve that, divide that number by two and deduct additional 20 percent for headroom, so 100 mb is about as fast as a wireless n router will achieve. A newer wireless AC router will go faster provided you device can connect at that speed. Your only as fast as the weakest link in the chain.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the RIGHT answer. I was experiencing the exact same problem with my linksys router. With just this one setting change I got back 80% of my internet speed back.

**The solution**

*Out of desperation, I started tweaking random settings on my router and stumbled across one that finally worked. The directions for other routers may be a little different, but here’s what I did:

- Go to http://192.168.1.1 and login to your router. If you’ve never done this, look for instructions that came with your router or do a google search to find the default username and password.
- Find a page that has QoS settings. For the E1200, you need to click on “Applications & Gaming” and select the “QoS” sub-menu.
- Disable WMM Support.
- Click save.

That’s it. The second I disabled WMM support, the download speeds for my laptop and iPhone both jumped to 24 Mbps, perfectly matching my desktop.*

Link: http://www.ybrikman.com/writing/2012/02/19/got-slow-download-but-fast-upload/

Answer (score 0):

In most routers disabling WMM with downgrade your router to G speed which actually probably does improve overall average but is not the correct solutions. The real problem with the E2500 is two fold. One is that its wifi chips are not very strong. They do not have extra amplifying power as some more expensive routers. The E2500 is really a short range small apartment/home  router. The second problem is because its chips are weak it's far more susceptible to outside signal interference. This can reduce speed, cause dropped signals, and over active channel surfing especially on 2.4. I have this router and the noise levels go way up easily and the weak signal output is easily overcome by these outside signals from other routers, or 2.4 devices.